# How to: log operations (sql) on one or more Sybase tables?

Tags: logging, sybase

We have a hard to track-down bug in one of our systems, i.e. it appears very seldom and randomly so we figure good logging over an extensive time period would be helpful.

Therefore I would like to ask if it's possible in any way to let Sybase (12.5.X or 15.X) log the SQL operations that updates the contents of a specific table, i.e. inserts and updates. Note, it will do with just the data but preferably I would like to log the complete SQL-statement thus a simple trigger approach won't cut it.

Regaqrds, Ola

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think trigger + Sybase MDA monitoring tables like monProcessSQLText could help you.